# Why a $ℝ^2$ subspace in $ℝ^3$ should be a plane through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand why it should be a plane, but I don't understand why it should be a plane **through the origin**.

According to Strang's linear algebra book, a proper subspace must follow these 2 rules: 
 1. Subspace must be closed by vector + vector addition.
 2. Subspace must be closed by vector x scalar multiplication.

According to these 2 rules, I can have a plane which is not through the origin and still have rules obeyed.
I've created these images in Mathematica to help me visualize the question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The vectors should "start" from the origin and "end" at a point in the plane. Yours don't.

Comment: What is your "special point" in the picture? Why do the two vectors start from there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subspace must be closed under scalar multiplication.  Take any $(x,y,z)$ in your subspace, multiply it by the scalar $0$, and the result $0(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ must still be in your subspace.  Hence every subspace must contain the origin.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. $\alpha v$ won't be in it for $\alpha=0$.